# Ember addon and processing files

Tags: reactjs, ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs, ember-addon

I have successfully managed to render a React component inside of ember.
You can see the relevant code [here](https://github.com/A-Helberg/ember-react/compare/develop...2.11.0).

The basics being adding an addon, that uses the `preprocessTree` hook, to use `broccoli-react` to parse the jsx files as per [here](https://github.com/A-Helberg/ember-react/compare/develop...2.11.0#diff-722669d3c6fc417aea1a62b17e80b9e0R13). And a `ReactComponent` (which is an ember component) to wrap any react component.

This works well in ember cli 2.11.0 and 2.12.0, but in 2.13.0 and 2.14.0 something has changed and I can't figure out what.

I have narrowed the error down to [this](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-resolver/blob/master/addon/resolvers/classic/index.js#L287) line in ember-resolver, for some reason `this._moduleRegistry` in the newer versions don't have the react component but the older versions do...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled everything node. And started matching package versions 1 for 1 from the newer app into the older one, and it all works.